# Spring Batch Job to run on startup

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application when I start the spring boot application the job is not running.

how can i have it run once at startup and end execution once finished ?

- Java version : 17
- SpringBoot : 3.0.0

  gradle file

  ```
  dependencies {
      implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")
      implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch")
      implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
      runtimeOnly("com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8")
      annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
      runtimeOnly("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
      testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
      testImplementation("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test")
  }
  ```

  Here is the configuration:

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableBatchProcessing
  @EnableElasticsearchRepositories
  public class PhqBatchConfiguration {

      private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PhqBatchConfiguration.class);
      private DataSource dataSource;

      @Autowired
      public PhqBatchConfiguration(DataSource dataSource) {
          this.dataSource = dataSource;
      }

      @Bean
      public PhqRangePartitioner partitioner(){
          return new PhqRangePartitioner(dataSource, 1000);
      }

      //Master
      @Bean(name = "partitionStep")
      public Step partitionStep(JobRepository jobRepository,
                                PhqRangePartitioner phqRangePartitioner){
          log.info("### creating partition step");
          return new StepBuilder("partitionStep", jobRepository)
                  .partitioner("partitionStep",phqRangePartitioner)
                  .build();
      }


      @Bean
      public Job partitionJob(JobRepository jobRepository, @Qualifier("partitionStep") Step partitionStep){
          log.info("### creating partition Job");
          return new JobBuilder("partitionJob", jobRepository).start(partitionStep).build();
      }

      @Bean(name = "phqReader")
      @StepScope
      public JdbcCursorItemReader<Phq> pagingItemReader(
              @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['ROWNUM_START']}")int rownumStart,
              @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['ROWNUM_END']}")int rownumEnd,
              @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['PARTITION_NAME']}")String partitionName){

          log.info("### creating paging item reader");
          PhqItemReader phqItemReader = new PhqItemReader(dataSource, partitionName,rownumStart,rownumEnd);
          return phqItemReader;
      }

      @Bean(name="importPhqStep")
      public Step importPhqStep(JobRepository jobRepository,
                                PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                @Qualifier("phqReader") JdbcCursorItemReader<Phq> phqItemReader,
                                ItemWriter<Phq> phqItemWriter){
          log.info("### creating import Phq step");
          return new StepBuilder("importStep", jobRepository)
                  .<Phq,Phq>chunk(1000, transactionManager)
                  .reader(phqItemReader)
                  .writer(phqItemWriter)
                  .build();
      }
  }
  ```

  Here is the log:

  ```
    .   ____          _            __ _ _
  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.0)

  2022-12-30T16:55:43.643+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] c.c.p.c.e.ElasticImporterApplication     : Starting ElasticImporterApplication using Java 17.0.5 with PID 57061 (/Users/ramseshughanta/workspace/cswg_ws/elastic-importer/build/classes/java/main started by ramseshughanta in /Users/ramseshughanta/workspace/cswg_ws/elastic-importer)
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.644+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] c.c.p.c.e.ElasticImporterApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.773+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.annotation.BatchRegistrar      : Finished Spring Batch infrastructure beans configuration in 2 ms.
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.777+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.777+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories in DEFAULT mode.
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.780+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1 ms. Found 0 Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.856+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.856+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories in DEFAULT mode.
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.860+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.861+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.862+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch repositories in DEFAULT mode.
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.863+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 0 ms. Found 0 Reactive Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.870+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.870+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.871+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 0 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
  2022-12-30T16:55:43.954+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.349+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1e253c9d
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.351+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.359+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: ORACLE
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.370+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] c.c.p.c.e.config.PhqBatchConfiguration   : ### creating partition step
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.381+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.382+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] c.c.p.c.e.config.PhqBatchConfiguration   : ### creating partition Job
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.384+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.385+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] c.c.p.c.e.config.PhqBatchConfiguration   : ### creating import Phq step
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.395+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.396+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
  2022-12-30T16:55:46.640+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [           main] c.c.p.c.e.ElasticImporterApplication     : Started ElasticImporterApplication in 3.118 seconds (process running for 3.322)
  2022-12-30T16:55:56.244+01:00  INFO 57061 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...

  Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
  ```

I followed this guid [Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the annotation `@EnableBatchProcessing`.

The automatic start of the job on application start-up is a Spring Boot feature. With Spring Boot 3, the auto-configuration behaves differently regarding `@EnableBatchProcessing` than before. The auto-configuration is now disabled when the annotation is present.